# Is there a way to use tfjs in Web Worker, if so is there a sample/example you could provide

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow.js

Is there a way to use tfjs in Web Worker, if so is there a sample/example you could provide. It looks like tfjs needs window and document global objects

I tried something like

```
let window = self;

importScripts("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs");
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a recent version of Chrome, try putting this before you import tfjs:

```
if (typeof OffscreenCanvas !== "undefined") {
  self.document = {
    readyState: "complete",
    createElement: () => {
      return new OffscreenCanvas(640, 480);
    }
  };

  self.window = {
    screen: {
      width: 640,
      height: 480
    }
  };
  self.HTMLVideoElement = OffscreenCanvas;
  self.HTMLImageElement = function() {};
  class CanvasMock {
    getContext() {
      return new OffscreenCanvas(0, 0);
    }
  }
  // @ts-ignore
  self.HTMLCanvasElement = CanvasMock;
}
```